# not able to upgrade maas to 1.4?

Tags: 13.04, server, upgrade, juju, maas

I am running ubuntu 13.04 LTS, and maas version runnung is maas 1.3+bzr1470+dfsg-0+1474+175~ppa0~ubuntu13.04.1, so i'm trying to upgrade it to mass 1.4 but its failing,

```
sam@xsmaas01:~$ sudo apt-get install maas
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  maas
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 87 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,912 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 85268 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace maas 1.3+bzr1470+dfsg-0+1474+175~ppa0~ubuntu13.04.1 (using .../maas_1.4+bzr1693+dfsg-0ubuntu2~ctools0_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement maas ...
Setting up maas-cluster-controller (1.4+bzr1693+dfsg-0ubuntu2~ctools0) ...
ERROR: Module version does not exist!
dpkg: error processing maas-cluster-controller (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maas:
 maas depends on maas-cluster-controller; however:
  Package maas-cluster-controller is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing maas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 maas-cluster-controller
 maas
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
sam@maas01:~$
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAAS has a lot of packages and dependencies. The central package, maas, should probably depend on similarly versioned dependencies, but it seems that it's not packaged that way. I suspect this is failing because you're not upgrading all of MAAS, or at least this is an aggravating factor.

I always use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Is there anything preventing you from updating all packages in the same way?

You could also try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller`, but try upgrading everything first if you can.